# Get matrix of minimum value from two equally sized matrix

Tags: r

I've looked everywhere but could find an answer.

I have to numerical matrix a

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

and b

```
3 1 4
5 2 1
```

and would like to get c equal to the minimum pairwise values of a and b

c

```
1 1 3
4 2 1
```

Thanks

Comment: Sorry I edited the matrix to be more specific. My actual matrices are huge so I need an efficient way to do it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pmin`, i.e.

```
pmin(m1, m2)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    1    3
#[2,]    4    2    1
```

**DATA:**

```
m1 <- matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
m2 <- matrix(c(3, 1, 4, 5, 2, 1), ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
```